# Как сохранить значения в переменную для анализа, telebot

Tags: python, telebot

```
balance = 1000
    

@bot.message_handler(commands=['crush'])
def send_crush(message):
    global balance
    koef 
    stavka

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, )
```

> Игра краш

> команда
> **/crush [коэфициент] [ставка(деньги)]**

> Как мне сохранить значение коэфициент в переменную koef для анализа? Так-же с ставкой, как сохранить ставку в переменную stavka

Answer (score 0):

```
balance = 1000
    

@bot.message_handler(commands=['crush'])
def send_crush(message):
    global balance
    koef = message.text.split()[1]
    stavka = message.text.split()[2]

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, )
```

Comment: koef, stavka = message.text.split()